# How to pass a predefined collection for simple_form input that represents enum fiels

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

is there any way to pass to simple_form field that represents an enum, first n statuses. For example I have:

enum status: [:user, :client, :admin, :super_user]

And I want for example if current.admin? - he can update other users only with :user, and client.
If current_user.super_user? - he can update users with :user, :client, :admin

=f.input_field :status, selected: @user.status

colletion: option seems not working for enum field, with others works fine

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the answer was ease, finally got it:

index = User.roles[current_user.role]
=f.input :status, User.roles.take(index) selected: @user.status